# How do I Print The Whole Contents Of A Paginated AngularJS UI-Grid On An MVC Page?

Tags: angularjs, printing, pagination, ui-grid

I have an MVC page, with data being displayed in an AngularJS UI_Grid, which is all working fine, and showing 10, 20 or 50 rows to a page.

However, I need to be able to print the whole list of data, even the rows that are displayed due to the pagination, all at once. Has anyone succeeded in doing this yet please?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to effectively print a different page (one view has paginated data, the other one has the whole set at once), it's usually best to provide a "print" button which opens a different view in a pop up that includes the other data. In this case, a non paginated view.

That page can then automatically do a `window.print();` when all the data is rendered, and then close itself, so that the user doesn't have to do anything other than hit the print button.

Comment: Thanks Dylan, I like your way of thinking :)